# Passbook file opens on Safari OSX, but not Safari iOS

Tags: ios, macos, mobile-safari, passbook, passkit

I'm trying to add Passbooks to my app. I've been fiddling with it all day and still no luck!

### Works on OSX Browsers

When I'm working locally (OSX), I download passbooks in Chrome and Safari and they open up just fine:

[image]

### Fails Silently on iOS Browsers

However, if I use the iOS simulator + Mobile Safari, I'm presented with an error message and *no log messages* :

[image]

If I use iPads (iOS 8 & 9), I get the same behavior: error message + nothing in the logs.

**One crazy thing**: we did have *one* successful open on an iPhone running iOS 9, but that's it. An earlier attempt with an iPhone on iOS 8 was not successful.

### Works on iMessage => iOS

My coworker downloaded the file from this question, sent it to his device by iMessage & installed it successfully. What in the world!!

### Example file

Here's an example `.pkpass` file: http://rmosolgo.github.io/assets/rm_example.pkpass

## What I've tried

#### Content-Type header

I've made sure I'm using the right content type. Here's the Rails code:

```
  format.pkpass {
    # This is just for testing: visit .pkpass to download a pass file just like the
    # one that would be attached to the email
    pkpass = pass.to_pkpass
    send_data(pkpass.stream.string, 
      filename: pass.to_pkpass_filename, 
      content_type: "application/vnd.apple.pkpass"
    ) 
  }
```

And it seems to come across in the GET request:

[image]

#### Valid JSON

I tried unzipping the `.pkpass` and inspecting the `pass.json`. All was well!

## What now??

I've seen lots of SO questions about this, but they all involve some kind of log output. I'm not getting any log output! What can I do? Do you have any suggestions??

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the github server where you have hosted the file is not sending the correct `Content-Type` header:

```
$ curl -I http://rmosolgo.github.io/assets/rm_example.pkpass

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: GitHub.com
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 23:00:53 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Expires: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 01:41:38 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=600
Content-Length: 748362
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 17 Sep 2015 01:31:38 GMT
Age: 0
X-Served-By: cache-iad2133-IAD
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1442453498.285053,VS0,VE7
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: MISS from liveandlearnatlanta.hotelwifi.com
Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 liveandlearnatlanta.hotelwifi.com (squid/3.3.2)
Connection: keep-alive
```

When served with the correct headers, the pass loads and ingests correctly.

However, the logs indicate that your register web service is not set up correctly and is issuing a `404` response instead of the expected `201`.

```
Sep 16 21:35:35 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709
Sep 16 21:35:35 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
Sep 16 21:35:42 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709
Sep 16 21:35:42 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com/v1/devices/b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a/registrations/pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709>
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Request contains header field <Authorization: ApplePass 2ece029fc4b7abe8aedfe95fe2375815e2504cc58ad3111689e29f08f8dbb689>
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Request contains body dictionary {
        pushToken = 5d1844d7403dfeca24f8a2275c3161a801515f94c1e07909de5ea6aa85f08479;
    }
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709
Sep 16 21:35:43 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Verifying structure and signature for pass pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Signature validation: succeeded
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) got response with code 404
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com/v1/log>
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Request contains body dictionary {
        logs =     (
            "[2015-09-16 21:35:44 -0400] Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404"
        );
    }
Sep 16 21:35:44 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) will retry after 10 seconds
Sep 16 21:35:45 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Log task (pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) got response with code 200
Sep 16 21:35:54 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com/v1/devices/b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a/registrations/pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn/89709>
Sep 16 21:35:54 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Request contains header field <Authorization: ApplePass 2ece029fc4b7abe8aedfe95fe2375815e2504cc58ad3111689e29f08f8dbb689>
Sep 16 21:35:54 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Request contains body dictionary {
        pushToken = 5d1844d7403dfeca24f8a2275c3161a801515f94c1e07909de5ea6aa85f08479;
    }
Sep 16 21:35:55 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) got response with code 404
Sep 16 21:35:55 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404
Sep 16 21:35:55 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Generating POST request with URL <https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com/v1/log>
Sep 16 21:35:55 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Request contains body dictionary {
        logs =     (
            "[2015-09-16 21:35:55 -0400] Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) encountered error: Unexpected response code 404"
        );
    }
Sep 16 21:35:55 iPhone passd[140] <Warning>: Register task (for device b0d117f8963f3d5103637f4ca990e69a, pass type pass.com.PlanningCenter.CheckIn, serial number 89709; with web service url https://check-ins-staging.planningcenteronline.com) will retry after 10 seconds
```

[image: Added Pass Front]
[image: Added Pass Back]

Comment: Thanks for your testing! I saw you had answered the other Passbook questions and I hoped you would find this one! I saw your logs were from iPhone and ... sure enough: works on iPhone, not on iPad. I guess iPad doesn't support passbooks!

Comment: Correct, Passbook is not and has never been supported on  the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Don't test passbooks on iPads -- it doesn't seem to work. For me, a real iPhone worked and iOS simulator worked if I used an iPhone!